# Compatibility between D3.js and Firefox v55.0.3

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, svg, compatibility

I'm developing a Data Analysis project for three months which uses almost exclusively d3.js v4 library, using Firefox. On August 25th with an automatic update, Firefox's version is changed from 54 to 55.0.3. After Firefox's updating the visualization of the graphic elements it was no longer the same: all `svg` and `g` components are wrongly positioned. Using instead Firefox's previous version (54) this issue is not present. How fix it?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1390088 Looks like it will be fixed in version 56.